# inline in block scope function declaration

Tags: c++

What does the following means?

> **ISO/IEC 14882:2011**
>
> 7.1.2 Function specifiers [dcl.fct.spec]
>   ...
>   3 ... The inline specifier shall not appear on a block scope function
>   declaration.

Is smth like this is invalid according to this quote or not?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    inline void foo();
    foo();
}

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "::foo() \n";
}
```

gcc compiles it without any error.

Am i wrong or not?

Comment: `Am i wrong or not?`  why don't you run it and see what happens

Comment: Because i want to know what standard really say about it... And yes, i tried it - "gcc compiles it without any error"

Answer (score 4):

> Is smth like this is invalid according to this quote or not?

Yes, it is in invalid because of the Standard paragraph you quote in the question's text.

The fact that the compiler accepts it may either be a bug or a documented extension, but is definitely not conforming to the C++11 Standard.

*Additional information:*

When I try to compile the above program with GCC 4.7.2, I get a warning that says:

> warning: `'inline'` specifier invalid for function `'foo'` declared out of global scope [`-pedantic`]

Comment: `gcc` stays silent on a lot of issues without setting certain compiler flags. It can get very particular if they're all turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I think `gcc` is tricking itself here. This should be illegal. What is happening here is `gcc` adds `inline void foo();` to its symbol table and **considers it undefined**. So the call `foo();` should be undefined as far as it is concerned.

However when the linker (`ld`) later tries to link the code it finds the definition of the `foo` in global scope which is reachable and uses that instead.

Comment: Making a call to a forward-declared function is certainly legal.  the only questionable part of this code is the `inline` keyword.